# JWT for angular2 based on systemJS

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I have tried the github tutorial to use JWT

https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

after that I have edited the systemjs file as follow.

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    "/angular2-jwt": {
      "defaultExtension": "js"
    }
  },
  map: {
    "angular2-jwt": "node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js"
  }
 });
```

but im having an issue : Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!

this error goes when I remove authHttp from the constructor.